# Docker: how to copy and install packages from previous build layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian, tesseract

I need a package version (tesseract-ocr 3.04) that I can only get from Debian 9; then I switch to a later Debian.

The problem is that I can't seem to `COPY` the package in such a way that it's installed in the next stage.

Here's where I'm at:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:9 as builder

RUN apt update && apt install -y tesseract-ocr

FROM debian

COPY --from=builder [???]
```

I've tried copying all the spots where I can find `tesseract-ocr` into their equivalent locations, but

1. I'm not sure I'm actually capturing everything
2. If I try to interactively check tesseract's version later, it says tesseract isn't installed.  (As a sanity check, it does install correctly in the first RUN step.)

How can I copy the package from Debian 9 into the next FROM stage in such a way that it's actually installed?

Comment: The OS-level package managers don't really work that way; files will be installed into `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib` and `/usr/share` and other system directories in a way that's hard to specifically pick out with Dockerfile `COPY --from` commands.  You might see if you can `dpkg --install` the older package in the newer image, but it may not work well.

Comment: @davidmaze Hmmm, is what I'm trying to do un common, or is there a preferred method?